# Retrieving same variable from all files of a repo

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm trying to make a database of all the values of two specific variables across an entire codebase.

Getting the raw files and parsing through them would work, but won't work in the future and I plan to run this often to keep the db up to date with all other files that have been created.

I imagine that it could be something along the lines of

```
for file in all_files
    from file import var1, var2
    db.append({var1, var2})
```

but I need to access these files from another repo in GitLab and it seems like the only output from GitLab is a raw file. Also, 'file in 'from file' doesn't work, it needs to be the actual file, not a var of the file's path.

Has anyone else come across a situation like this?

Edit: clarification

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this won't work in the future? What is this "raw file"?

Comment: The raw file is a result of GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path/raw
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html goes into more detail. 
Parsing is something I'm trying to get away from and could be unreliable with all the different verisons of this variable structure that I'm dealing with.